Have the words Φιλος and φυλλο ever been related?
I thought, that the concept of φυλλο tribe, leave, stem is in respect to the developpement of early civilisations more ancient  than the concept of φilo, friend. In Homers time, when Odysseus was knocking at the door of a city, the question was: stranger or friend? But I wondered, whether they didn‘t rather ask: stranger or one of own tribe? So my question is: were there always two words for φιλος and φυλλο. Do they have a common etymological origin or are they totally independent? And which one is the older word?

Welcome to the site! Did you look up the etymologies of these words anywhere yourself? If yes, what did you learn and what remains unclear?

Dear Jooonas, I looked it up, but did not get very far. I don‘t know ancient greek and only consulted modern greek and english sources. So the question remains, if the source of φιλος is φυλο/φυλλο (if φυλο is more ancient than φιλος)?

Do you actually mean φυλλο? That's the Modern Greek form of φῠ́λλον "leaf". The word for tribe is φῡλή. Both those two words are from the same root (that of the verb φῠ́ω "to bring forth"), so it's not overly important to the question, but I wanted to check

I understand that you didn't get far, but it'd still help getting a useful answer to add a description of where you did get in your question. The question itself is clear, so it's all about making answers more useful and more likely to come.

Let us quote the relevant entries from Robert Beekes' Etymological Dictionary of Greek:
φίλος.

For the epic aorist forms (ἐ-)φίλατο, etc., analogical origin to φιλέω
is well possible (cf. δοκέω beside ἔδοξα); there is no need to assume
a present *φίλλω. The element φιλο-, which occurs only in PNs, may
have arisen analogically to φιλο-: Φιλτo-ξενος to Φιλό-ξενος like e.g.
Φαντ-αγόρας beside Φαν-αγόρας, Φαντ-ίας beside Φαν-ίας. φίλτρον seems
to have joined the numerous instrument nouns in -τρον; the causative
meaning ‘stimulating love’ is clear.
The original meaning of φίλος was ‘own, accompanying’ rather than
‘beloved’. The etymology is unknown; the connection with a
Celto-Germanic adjective for ‘fitting, good, etc.’ (Ir. bil, W
Bil- in PNs, OHG bil-līh, etc.) must be abandoned. Lyd. bilis ‘his, her’ looks formally similar, but must be explained within
Anatolian (from the pronoun bi- ‘he’). Some have argued that φίλος
represents an l-derivative of reflexive *σφι, Lac. φιν (see
Landfester op. cit.: 34ff. with a review of all earlier etymologies);
in that case, the original meaning would be ‘one’s own’.

φυλή.

Old derivative from φῦναι, with a suffix -(s)l-. For further
etymology, see φύομαι [“I am produced, grown”, with no etymological connection to φύλλον].

φύλλον.
Briefly, Beekes associates the word with Latin folium 'leaf' directly from a PIE root. Its cognates have the meaning of flowering, blossom.
The entry phylai of The Oxford Classical Dictionary (Oxford University Press, 4th edition, 2012) says

The Greek word phyle, usually but misleadingly translated "tribe",
was widely but not universally used in the Greek world to denote the
principal components or divisions of the citizen body. Their origins
are unclear. Entities so called are unknown to epic, except for the
anomalous line Homer, Iliad 2.363, but their use in Aegean and
colonial contexts suggests that they existed well before the 8th cent.
BC.
Two sets are well attested in the Archaic period: the Dorian tribes
Hylleis, Dymanes, and Pamphyloi, known as such in 7th-cent. Sparta
(Tyrtaeus F 19 West) and elsewhere, and the Ionian-Attic tribes
Geleontes, Hopletes Argadeis, Aigikoreis, Oinopes, and Boreis, known
in Archaic Athens (the first four), some Aegean islands, and Ionia.
Northwestern Greece, Boeotia, Thessaly, and the areas of Aeolic
dialect (Lesbos etc.) used no such divisions till the Hellenistic
period, using instead phratries (Thessaly) or the formalized merē
('parts', 'sections') of federal Boeotia (Hell. Oxy. 19 Chambers).
Hence the systematization of the Dorian and the Ionian-Attic
tribe-systems is likely to reflect on the one hand the processes which
yielded the main dialects of Greek, and on the other the process of
city-state formation in the Dark Age, which was slow to affect central
and northern Greece.

The mentioned from Iliad is ὡς φρήτρη φρήτρηφιν ἀρήγῃ, φῦλα δὲ φύλοις for which one transation is "let clan help clan, tribes help tribes."
I think, we can conclude that a distinctive connection among φίλος, φυλή and φύλλον does not exist.
